# I want to record video from webcam

Tags: matlab, webcam, video-recording

I am using Matlab code for that.

But when I run it, It shows errors.

**Code :**

```
fig=figure;
set(fig,'DoubleBuffer','on');
set(gca,'xlim',[-80 80],'ylim',[-80 80],'NextPlot','replace','Visible','off');
mov = avifile('movie.avi','compression','cinepak');
mov.quality=90;
i=imread('white.jpg');
for k=1:1000
imshow(i);
F = getframe(gca);
mov = addframe(mov,F);
end
mov = close(mov);
```

**Errors :**

```
??? Error using ==> capturescreen
Figure destroyed during getframe

Error in ==> getframe at 35
x=capturescreen(varargin{:});

Error in ==> a at 9
F = getframe(gca);
```

Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here, although I had to change compression to 'None' since RLE and MSVC won't won't work with the truecolor image I was using and indeo/cinepak wouldn't work with x64.  (Not either version of indeo, oddly)

My guess was that you needed a `drawnow` after your `imshow` command to clear the buffer so you have an image to copy.  I produced a different error the first time I ran it, which seemed to confirm that, but I couldn't reproduce that one.  It definitely works with the drawnow; in.

**Update:** For anyone running win7 x64, you should be able to use 'i420' as your codec.  Using that the above code works fine for me either with `drawnow` in after imshow or not.